# Python 3 code for a binary search tree

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, tree, binary-search

I am working on a [**python3.6.5** question about BST](https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/binary-search-tree/24973?visibility=1&skillId=9):

> Binary search tree (BST) is a binary tree where the value of each node is larger or equal to the values in all the nodes in that node's left subtree and is smaller than the values in all the nodes in that node's right subtree.
>
> Write a function that, **efficiently with respect to time used**, checks if a given binary search tree contains a given value.
>
> For example, for the following tree:
>
> - n1 (Value: 1, Left: null, Right: null)
> - n2 (Value: 2, Left: n1, Right: n3)
> - n3 (Value: 3, Left: null, Right: null)
>
> Call to `contains(n2, 3)` should return `True` since a tree with root at n2 contains number 3.

My code is:

```
import collections

Node = collections.namedtuple('Node', ['left', 'right', 'value'])

def contains(root, value):
    if value == root.value:
        return True

    if value > root.value:
        if root.right != None:
            return contains(root.right, value)
    else:
        if root.left != None:
            return contains(root.left, value)


n1 = Node(value=1, left=None, right=None)
n3 = Node(value=3, left=None, right=None)
n2 = Node(value=2, left=n1, right=n3)

print(contains(n2, 3))
```

It can work but the website only gave me a 33% score. I found some similar questions, but they are based on c++. I want to know is there any way to improve my code to get a better score based on python3?

Comment: Your question is off-topic for Code Review, because the result is only 33% correct. Our rules require that the code work correctly before we can review it. See the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Note that your function never returns `False`. (It can sometimes return `None`.)

Comment: Does the website give any comments or feedback? Or just a score of 33%?  Perhaps they want an iterative solution instead of a recursive one.

Comment: What does a score of 33% mean, that it fails some of the test cases? If that's so, your code is not ready for review yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) pointed out in the comments, your function will never return `False`. Try to follow the function code in this case: what if you arrive to a node that has no left/right nodes? You will arrive at the end of the function, where there is no return statement. Adding a `return False` there gives me 100% score.

As a recommendation, instead of nesting to `if`s you can use the `and` operator to chain conditions. Also, to check if something is (not) `None`, it's better to use `x is not None`:

```py
if value > root.value and root.right is not None:
    return contains(root.right, value)

elif root.left is not None:
    return contains(root.left, value)

else:
    return False
```